# Why does the wrong ID keep Populating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have run into a very odd situation, that I have not experienced before. In our code, we wanting to check the value of BillingDomainID once the page is loaded. Wrapped in a function with many other jQuery functions inside, I have the following code:

```
var vBDID = ".BillingDomainID" + $("#BillingDomainID").val() + "";
        alert(vBDID);
        $(".BillingDomainID").show();
        $(vBDID).toggle();
```

We are using vBDID to dynamically create a class that will hide certain fields in the form if the BillingDomainID != 1. The Value exists in a hidden field that is at the bottom of the page. Since we have 7 BillingDomainIDs in our system, Anytime the BillingDomainID = 1 it will show the fields, and anytime it is 2-7, it hides them because of the classes that we have placed on the fields that we want to hide.

So here is the issue that I having. The alert that appears in the code above will say that the vaule of vBDID is .BillingDomainID2 for example, but the real value of the #BillingDomainID is 1 in the Database. Why is it that the value is being presented as a different value in the website, that it is in the database? Everything else works as it should, with the exception to this part.

I should also mention, that we are using ajax to change value when the Office dropdown is changed. This part also works fine, and the BillingDomainID will actually be correct after it is changed once. It is only initially when the page loads that it is incorrect.

Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: We would need to see the code that extracts the data from the DB as well.

Comment: It is better, if you add some HTML here, to be more clear with the issue!

Comment: If I well understand, it works fine when `#BillingDomainID` value is modified through Ajax, while it's wrong when it came with the entire complete original page? If so, it might be the server script fault: did you really checked the `#BillingDomainID` content _in the HTML source of the received page_?